# Extract Sub-String from String in Excel (No VBA)

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, extract

I have a series of paths in excel which follow the pattern:

```
C:\Folder\Subfolder1\SURNAME, Firstname\Subfolder2\SURNAME, Firstname - YYYY MM DD - Invoice.pdf
```

I cannot use VBA, so using an array formula, how would I extract SURNAME, Firstname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),3*LEN(A1)+1,LEN(A1)))
```

Where `3*` could be read as *n-1*, so change to whichever number to get the nth substring from a delimited string.

Another option, with access to `FILTERXML`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()=4]")
```

This would essentially pull the 4th substring from a "\" delimited string. Change `position()=4` to the *nth* position if you like to retrieve other substrings. This option seems a bit longer, but could become handy when you want to retrieve multiple substrings where you just need to change up the `XPATH`.

---

After your commend, I think you might want to try:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A6," - ","\"),"\","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()=last()-2]")
```

Comment: Both are brilliant, JvdV, but return everything after the last "\". I only need to return from the last "\" to the "-". Path lengths are also variable, so the last slash would need to be calculated. I will be able to use your solution elsewhere, however. Thanks!

Comment: @BadDogTitan, I see what you are trying now then, have a look at the update.

Comment: Works as advertised. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))),1)),FIND("-",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",""))),1)))-2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Or try,

In `B1` copied across right until blank and all copied down :

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE("\"&MID($A1,FIND("\",$A1,4)+1,FIND("-",$A1,4)-FIND("\",$A1,4)-2),"\",REPT(" ",199)),COLUMN(A1)*399,199))
```

[image]